# Pytorch resume model training

Tags: pytorch

I've preserved the model's state_dict(), but unfortunately, the optimizer's state_dict() is lost. Can I still continue training the PyTorch model from the last checkpoint?

Please confirm any limitations if I resume with a new optimizer object but a model with pre-trained weights. Any benefit I can get with this approach?

I possess all the optimizer hyperparameters, and if I generate an optimizer object with these parameters to resume training, what would be the consequences?"